# Importing data from mysql into python,how to get rid of variable type?

Tags: python, mysql

I am importing from mysql database and getting data in following format Decimal('1236.1500'), Decimal('1243.9500'),

How do i get rid of this decimal and store it in a separate list as (1236.15,1253.95)?

Code being used

```
def retrive_stock_open_price(ticker):

tick=ticker
sql="""SELECT open_price FROM daily_price WHERE ticker='%s' ORDER by price_date"""%(tick)
with con:
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql)
    data=cur.fetchall()

return [[d[0]] for d in data]
```

Comment: I am using python MySQLdb module, MySqL as my database

Comment: You can convert from a `Decimal` instance `d` to `float` instance `f` using `f = float(d)`. Also, read [the docs on `list`s](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Comment: I have same problem with date, how do i convert to python date?

Comment: You don't need to "get rid" of anything. You should show the code you are using and any errors you get.

Comment: One useful technique to learn is to [RTFM](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).